# get the subnetid from subnets of type map(object)

Tags: azure, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I need to fetch the subnetid from azurerm_subnet data resource as subnet is used in dynamic block of azurerm_virtual_network as map(object) type

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  dynamic "subnet" {
    for_each = var.subnets
    content {
      name           = subnet.value.name
      address_prefix = subnet.value.address_prefix
      security_group = azurerm_network_security_group.example[subnet.key].id
    }
  }
}
```

Fetch the second subnetid to attach it to storage account

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  count                    = length(var.subnets)
  name                     = "storageaccountname"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"

  network_rules {
    default_action             = "Deny"
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = ["${data.azurerm_subnet.subnetid.id}"]
  }
}
```

Please can any one help to solve as i want to declare subnet in azurerm_virtual_network as dynamic block and get the subnet if from the data resource and please find my terraform.tfvars as below

```
subnets = {
  subnet1 = {
    name           = "subnet1"
    address_prefix = "10.0.0.0/24"
  }
  subnet2 = {
    name           = "subnet2"
    address_prefix = "10.0.1.0/24"
  }
  subnet3 = {
    name           = "subnet3"
    address_prefix = "10.0.2.0/24"
  }
}
```

Comment: Current approach has few flaws. (1). you are using the count on `azurerm_storage_account` with `length(var.subnets)` which by your `tfvars`  is `3`.  which is logically not correct you can not create three storage account with same name in the first place. (2). You are using a data source for input but has not defined in the code anyware.  More details are needed ,error message and what exactly you want to achieve , one storage account with network rules allowing one subnet or dynamic stg. accounts on the basis of subnets and with one to one mapping in network rules.

Comment: `security_group = azurerm_network_security_group.example[subnet.key].id`. this also looks fishy but because no relevant code is shared it's not possible for me to make direct comments.

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_network

Comment: I used below to fetch specific subnet id by name as var.subnets.subnet2.name (But i want a solution without name specification and it should get the second subnet ID)

data block data "azurerm_subnet" "subnetid" {
  name                 = var.subnets.subnet2.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_virtual_network.example.resource_group_name
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_virtual_network.example
  ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### IMPORTANT

`count = length(var.subnets)` in **resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {}** is still there in your question which is logically incorrect as I have stated in the comments.

##### Answer

With your comments, I am assuming that you want to use `id` of `subnet2` in `network_rules` of  **resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {}**. With your current approach where creating subnets within the virtual network resource you have to use [splat](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/splat) expressions and [locals](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/locals) to make a map out of the `set` object and then can directly refer wherever is required.

> While doing referencing even with `locals` and `splat expressions` it is still required to use the name of the subnet as it is not possible for terraform to know what you want without any data.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  dynamic "subnet" {
    for_each = var.subnets

    content {
      name           = subnet.value.name
      address_prefix = subnet.value.address_prefix
      # security_group = azurerm_network_security_group.example[subnet.key].id ## I have ignored it as no relevant code is shared### 
    }
  }
}

locals {
  subnets = { for subnet in azurerm_virtual_network.example.subnet : subnet.name => subnet }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  #count                    = length(var.subnets) ## Removed it too as logically incorrect with the current code ##
  name                     = "storageaccountname"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"

  network_rules {
    default_action             = "Deny"
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = [local.subnets.subnet2.id]
  }
```

You do not need a data source when referencing the attributes from one resource/module to another resource/module in the root module.

However, I suggest using [azurerm_subnet](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/subnet) resource for easier reference in spite of creating subnets in the virtual network resource itself because your might need `Microsoft.Storage` [service_endpoints](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/subnet#service_endpoints) in your subnets for working with storage account with network_rules.

Comment: Hi Ishuar, Thanks for your response and it worked. Just want to check do we have any solution to fetch exactly 2nd subnet in map(object) instead of virtual_network_subnet_ids = [local.subnets.subnet2.id] hardcoded value(subnet2). And I totally agree with your statement on separating subnet resource  from azurerm_virtual_network resource